# sharing videos from flutter application directly on whatsapp status

Tags: flutter

I want to make an app which can share videos directly on whatsapp/Instagram stories. Its been more than 10 days and I have searched the whole internet but didn't find anything. similar questions have been asked by the users on stack but nobody replied . Is it impossible to share videos directly on whatsapp/Instagram story?